# Creating table in LaTeX

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[H]
%   \begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Specifications of LTE}
        \label{tab:table1}
        %\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tabular}{ | l |l |p{5cm} |} 
                \hline
                Feature & Details\\
                \hline
                Latency& lessthan 10ms from user to server   \\ \hline
                Mobility& Up to 35km/hr,optmized for 15km/s\\ \hline
                Coverage& Full up to 5km,sight degradation 5-15 operating up to 100km\\
                Channel Bandwidth& 1.4,3,5,10,15,20 \\  \hline
                Mdulation Schemes&UL:QPSK,16QAM,64QAM{{optional} DL:QPSK,16QAM,64QAM\\
                    \hline
                    Multiple Access Scheme&DL:OFDM UL:SC-FDMA   \\ \hline
                    Modes& TDD and FDD   \\ \hline
                    Multi-Antenna Technology& MIMO, DL:1*2,2*2,4*2,4*4   \\ \hline
                    Peak Date Rate& With 20MHZ slot and 4*4 MIMO peakdownlink 300Mbps,Uplink 75Mbps  \\ \hline

            \end{tabular} }
            %\end{adjustbox} 
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

After compiling, it gives this error

```
File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd.
```

and does not display the pdf output.

Comment: unpaired brace in `64QAM{{optional}`

Answer (score 4):

Brenda, there is an unpaired brace in `64QAM{{optional}` so, to prevent the error when compiling the document, either make it  `64QAM{{optional}}` OR `64QAM{optional}`, however, I suspect you intended the 'optional' to be inside standard brackets, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
%   \begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Specifications of LTE}
        \label{tab:table1}
        %\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tabular}{ | l |l |p{5cm} |} 
                \hline
                Feature & Details\\
                \hline
                Latency& lessthan 10ms from user to server   \\ \hline
                Mobility& Up to 35km/hr,optmized for 15km/s\\ \hline
                Coverage& Full up to 5km,sight degradation 5-15 operating up to 100km\\
                Channel Bandwidth& 1.4,3,5,10,15,20 \\  \hline
                Mdulation Schemes&UL:QPSK,16QAM,64QAM({optional}) DL:QPSK,16QAM,64QAM\\
                    \hline
                    Multiple Access Scheme&DL:OFDM UL:SC-FDMA   \\ \hline
                    Modes& TDD and FDD   \\ \hline
                    Multi-Antenna Technology& MIMO, DL:1*2,2*2,4*2,4*4   \\ \hline
                    Peak Date Rate& With 20MHZ slot and 4*4 MIMO peakdownlink 300Mbps,Uplink 75Mbps  \\ \hline

            \end{tabular} }
            %\end{adjustbox} 
        \end{center}
    \end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

Nicholas Hamilton has already explained your error, but I'd like to suggest to you some improvements.

In my opinion, your table could be clearer without all those rules (especially the vertical ones).

Moreover, you should use `\centering`, not the `center` environment within a `table` environment, see here: [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables).

Instead of resizing your table to fit the page, you could choose a smaller font (`\small`, `\scriptsize`, `\tiny`) and/or use `tabularx`.

Finally, I didn't know what your text means (hence I didn't change it), but I think you should have a look at [`siunitx` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering\small
        \caption{Specifications of LTE\label{tab:table1}}
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX} 
                \toprule
                Feature & Details\\
                \midrule
                Latency& Less than 10ms from user to server   \\ 
                Mobility& Up to 35km/hr, optmized for 15km/s\\
                Coverage& Full up to 5km, sight degradation 5-15 operating up to 100km\\
                Channel Bandwidth& 1.4, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20 \\
                Modulation Schemes&\makecell[tl]{UL: QPSK, 16QAM, 64QAM (optional)\\ DL: QPSK, 16QAM, 64QAM}\\
                Multiple Access Scheme&DL: OFDM UL: SC-FDMA   \\
                Modes& TDD and FDD   \\
                Multi-Antenna Technology& MIMO, DL: 1*2, 2*2, 4*2, 4*4   \\ 
                Peak Date Rate& With 20MHZ slot and 4*4 MIMO peakdownlink 300Mbps, Uplink 75Mbps  \\ 
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `siunitx` is indeed recommended; for instance it would avoid errors such as “hr” instead of “h” and “MHZ” instead of “MHz”.